# Action_MOVE activate after Action_UP

Tags: java, android, ontouchlistener, motionevent

I am creating a game , and I  want my character turn left or right by Action_MOVE, but only after the user takes their finger off of the display. I have a class that detects whether MotionEvent is MOVE or UP.

Comment: Good....Keep going ..who stop you..

Comment: When i first time make MOVE i save starting point and when i get UP action i compare them whether x1>x2 or not but its don't work

Comment: I don't mean to hurt you...but you should provide some code and have to show what have you tried before asking...

Comment: I just need to know when move is over , is up called?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think you can rely on MotionEvent.ACTION_UP